# What is the name of the helmet shown on the loading screen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I saw a helmet during a loading screen and can't figure out what it is. I know it's not part of any of the sets, but I can't figure out what it is.

[image: Mysterious Helmet]

Anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The helmet in question is the [Blades Helmet](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blades_Helmet_%28Skyrim%29):**

[image: Blades Helmet]

---

> It's all black with three gold claw like things trailing back down the helmet originating from one point in the dead center of the crown of the helmet.

Helmets similar to your *initial description* **that also appear on loading screens** are:
[The Jagged Crown](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown_%28Item%29) (left) and the [drangonscale helmet](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonscale_Helmet) (right).

[image: The Jagged Crown][image: Dragonscale helmet]

Comment: the blades helmet also appears in loading screens if I remember correctly

Comment: @spartacus major hat-tip in your direction for the hint to the answer, I haven't pursued the Blades quests myself so I don't think I'd triggered their artifacts in the loading screen

Comment: @Rory I haven't done their quests yet either, matter of fact I've been avoiding the main questline like the plague, but it still shows up often enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Blades Helmet. I think its a carry on from Oblivion as you can get a sweet set of blades armour on that too. As for the golden trims on the top it is a dragon to signify that they were once great dragonslayers.

Comment: heres another tip without meaning to sound condiscending the description in the bottom right corner usually gives a good insight into the origin of the item displayed